# When does the .NET framework need to be installed on a client machine?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm not entirely sure when the .NET framework needs to be installed on a client's machine when building C# apps.

Say for instance there is a console application as such:

```
﻿using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HelloWorld{
    class Hello {
        static void Main() {                    
             MessageBox.Show("Hello World.");
        }
    }
}
```

Would the client be required to install the .NET run times? Could this be bypassed by including the System.Windows.Forms.dll and merging it in the exe?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the .NET framework is always required. System.Windows.Forms is a .NET assembly, so statically linking to it (somehow) won't help. However, some version of .NET is pretty much guaranteed to be installed these days. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Versions

Comment: Yep, if you know what operating system versions you're supporting, you can usually target a version of the framework and be sure it will work (Personally, I find myself targeting 2-3.5) when going for no-framework-install compatability, depending on the audience. That said, creating an installer which bundles the framework is usually fairly simple, if not trivial

Comment: Thanks for your answer guys, so if I target .NET 3.5, I should have out of the box compatibility with W7,8,8.1, and 10 if I'm understanding Common Language Infrastructure correctly, correct? (assuming I'm not making any 4+ dependent calls.)

Comment: If you want to make such a simple application and minimize the dependency footprint, .NET might not be the way to go.

Comment: Unlike the Java Virtual Machine, you can't xcopy the .NET Framework to Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.NET Framework must be installed. Even if you embed parts of the .NET framework into your assembly (eg. using Fody/Costura) or include them as DLLs, .NET framework assemblies are almost never standalone. For example, `System.Windows.Forms.dll` would reference parts of the .NET framework that are external to `System.Windows.Forms.dll`.

Luckily, .NET framework is usually installed on Windows by default, so to make life easy you could just target a certain version of Windows. For example, I usually target 4.0 and assume the user is running Windows 7 SP1 or later. Anyone with up-to-date Windows 7 should be running SP1 as it's a Windows Update.

Here is a table of which .NET versions come on which OS ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Versions)).

```
Windows Version | Default .NET
==============================
XP              | None
Vista           | 3.0
7               | 3.5
7 SP1           | 4.0
8               | 4.5
8.1             | 4.5.1
10              | 4.6
```

If you need to know how to change the target framework, [try this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx). Basically, go to the project properties and change "Target Framework".